# How to configure Log4j (1 or 2) to use custom log file name while code against Slf4j

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, slf4j

I know there has been a lot of question related to this, but i couldn't find one that matches on the scenario that i'm looking at, so here's the question.

Current logging setup: logger coded using **Slf4j** with **Log4j 1.2** bindings. `DailyRollingAppender` used.

The program: A multi-threading backend Java program processing data from a table and call relevant web services.

A new request came in to have the log file name be based on a certain data, lets call it `match_code`. With this, whenever a thread is processing say `MatchA`, then the log file the thread use should be set as `MatchA.log`

I'd googled for a while and understand that i will need to programmatically configure the Log4j configuration whenever the processes starts, the question is how should i change the log file name settings while not affecting others setting such as the `Patterns`.

I'm open to switch to Log4j 2.x if it means that can solve my problem, so far have no luck in finding samples for this.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE on what's tried**

Tried using the `System.setProperty` way to dynamically set the log file. Here's the properties setting:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/log/${logfile.name}.log
```

In main class, added these two lines before anything else:

```
    static{
        System.setProperty("logfile.name","output");
    }

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Engine.class);
```

Added this right after the process found data to be process:

```
System.setProperty("logfile.name",match_code+"_output");
```

where `match_code` is a value from database such as 'MatchA'

The result is, the main class DID have the log named as `output.log`. However if i put in data to test, the log will still goes to `output.log` and there's no new log file created based on the data.

Comment: errr any reason why it's downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if I understand your problem: you want your same log message goes to different log file, depending on the data you are processing?

if you use LogBack, you can do it by combination of MDC + SiftingAppender.  For example, in your code, you can do:

(in code)

```
MDC.put("match_code", "MatchA");
logger.debug("whatever message");  // just log it normally
```

(in logback.xml)

```
  <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
      <key>match_code</key>
      <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
      <appender name="FILE-${match_code}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${match_code}.log</file>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
      </appender>
    </sift>
  </appender>
```

Please note, here I am using LogBack as logging backend.  There is no official sifting appender for Log4j 1.  I kind of remember something similar in Log4j 2.  Wish this can serve as your starting point of searching if you really insist to use Log4j

Comment: hi, yes i wish to log to different log files based on the data value. I did look at LogBack but because i'm using SLF4J at the code level, i'm not sure whether this will impact it or not.

Comment: No, there should be no problem.  That's the whole purpose of using SLF4J: you can switch logging backend without affecting your code.  And Logback is the native implementation of logging backend for SLF4J, there is supposed to be least problem using it as your logging backend.

Comment: sounds good, let me work on it and see how it goes. Thanks a lot!